# std::map, std:unordered_map и ключ-структура

Tags: c++, ссылки, map, struct, unordered-map

Есть вот такая простенькая структура:

```
struct Point
{
    ll X;
    ll Y;

    Point(ll a = 0, ll b = 0)
    {
        X = a;
        Y = b;
    }
};
```

Требуется словарь с ключем в качестве этой структуры. Для map нужно перегружать оператор "<", это понятно. unordered_map оператор "<" не требуется, зато вот так ругается:

> c++\bits\hashtable_policy.h|85|error: no match for call to '(const std::hash) (const Point&)'|

Каким образом исправлять?

И еще один момент. Возможно ли организовать передачу аргументов в конструктор структуры по ссылке, чтобы была возможность создания массива данной структуры? 
По (ll &a, ll &b) массив создать не может, ввиду отсутствия инициализации. Каким образом инициализацию по ссылкам организовать? Вариант без ссылок крайне нежелателен из-за огромного объема данных.

Comment: Не понял. Какое отношение передача параметров по ссылке имеет к созданию массивов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `std::unordered_map<>` нужны функции, вычисляющие хеш ключа и равенство ключей. Пример использования есть в [документации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map).

`upd:`

Для второго вопроса

```
struct Point
{
    ll X = 0;
    ll Y = 0;

    Point(ll& a) : X(a)
    {

    }

    Point(ll& a, ll& b) : X(a), Y(b)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: Речь о быстрой работе конструктора Point. Нужна передача по ссылке.
Если грубо, то ll &a = 0, ll &b = 0 (вопрос как это записать в рабочем виде), т.е. при создании объекта с явными аргументами передача по ссылкам, а при отсутствии таковых - заполнение нулями. Не совсем понятна логика вашей структуры. В частности ссылки X, Y;

Comment: Можно конечно создать отдельную переменную нуля ll z = 0, и  ll &a = z, ll &b = z в конструкторе. Но это уже быдлокодерство какое-то

Comment: @KhetagAbramov что означает запись "ll &a = 0, ll &b = 0 "? передачу параметров в конструктор по ссылкам + дефолтное значение `nullptr`?

Comment: ll &a = 0, ll &b = 0 - абстрактный пример, ничего общего с c++ не имеет, извиняйте. Именно, передача параметров по ссылкам или дефолтное значение 0. Говорить о том, зачем необходимы именно ссылки, думаю, не стоит.

Comment: @KhetagAbramov изменил ответ, если правильно вас понял

Answer (score 3):

Определите собственный функтор для вычисления хэша ваших структур. Вот один из возможных.

```
// собственная специализация std::hash, которую можно внедрить в пространство имён std
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<Point>
    {
        typedef Point argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t result_type;
        result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const noexcept
        {
            result_type const h1 ( std::hash<ll>{}(s.X) );
            result_type const h2 ( std::hash<ll>{}(s.Y) );
            return h1 ^ (h2 << 1); // или используйте boost::hash_combine
        }
    };
}
```

Другие примеры смотрите в описании [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).